# How to set a cookie based on URL when site visitor manually changes the URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I am working on a site redesign going from Joomla to MODX, and would like to duplicate something from the current site, but can't find where the code is that manages this. Basically, when a user comes to the site their location is determined by IP, and it sets the URL to something like `example.com/dc-metro` and sets a cookie called "market" to "dc-metro". There is a dropdown on the site for a visitor to change their location, so if they select "Chicago" for example, the URL becomes `example.com/chicago` and the market cookie is updated to a value of "chicago". That part works great, the issue I am having is, if a user is on `example.com/dc-metro/cool-things-to-do`, and instead of using the dropdown to change location, they manually change the URL to `example.com/chicago/cool-things-to-do`, the page refreshes, but the cookie is not updated.

Is there a way to do something like `$SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (or something like that) to pull from the URL and set the cookie when the page reloads. I have several places on the site that show a variable based on the market cookie, and these are not updating (for example, on my dropdown the default value is the current market location).

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: You can use either `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, then get the top-level directory from this and set the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parse_url` function. For example:

```
$url_path = parse_url($SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$path_parts = explode('/', trim($url_path,'/'));
$location = $path_parts[0];
```

$location variable will contain what you need. Then onlything that you need to do is set the cookie with the correct value. Use `setcookie` function for that.

Comment: Thank you! After some playing around I was able to use that and add a couple lines so that the cookie value updated immediately without manual page refresh. I really appreciate it.